# How to recognize if a lattice is distributive?

Tags: lattices, boolean-algebras, lattice-theory

I know that a Boolean lattice must be distributive.

But what with these lattices? Are these distributive?

$\hskip0.7in$[image]

How to recognize which lattices are distributive or not only by looking on their diagrams? Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  A lattice is distributive if and only if it does not contain the diamond lattice or the pentagon lattice as a sublattice.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice

Comment: not all of these are lattices in fact

Comment: So, none of these three are distributive. Am I right?

Comment: Isn't (ii) distributive?  Note that a sublattice must have the sames meets and joins as the original lattice.

Comment: Okay, everything is clear now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I am not sure this question deserves to be on hold. The question of how to recognize which lattices are distributive from their diagram is rather interesting. In addition to the classical result about $M_3$ and $N_5$, there is the result of Farley and Schmidt that a finite lattice is distributive if and only if every open interval is either an antichain or is connected, and every interval of rank three is distributive. (Up to isomorphism, there are five distributive lattices of rank three.) See *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, 2nd ed., Exercise 3.31.

Comment: I would be glad to vote to reopen this question if it were reworded a bit since there could be some interesting answers.

Comment: Reconsidering after these comments - yes I also agree there might be interesting approaches. One thought as an example: it is relatively easy to read out posets of join- and meet-irreducibles from the Hasse diagram. Now for distributivity it is certainly necessary that these posets be antiisomorphic. Presently I cannot find out whether this is also sufficient. What is certainly sufficient (and also necessary) is that this antiisomorphism be established through splitting (mutually complementary principal ideals/filters). This might be more tedious to verify from the picture but still possible.

Comment: Ooops, not antiisomorphic but isomorphic in fact...

Comment: The condition that the posets of join- and meet-irreducibles are isomorphic is certainly not sufficient for distributivity, e.g., a $k$-element antichain, $k>2$, with a top and bottom adjoined. I don't know whether the following is true: let $L$ be a finite lattice with maximal chain of length $n$. If $L$ has exactly $n$ join-irreducibles and $n$ meet-irreducibles, then $L$ is distributive.

Comment: I believe the Farley-Schmidt result Professor Stanley (or someone claiming to be Professor Stanley) mentions has as a hypothesis that the poset (it need not be a lattice) be bounded and graded of rank at least 3 (but I could be wrong).

Comment: Also, there is the nice result of Professor George Markowsky, that a finite lattice is distributive with n join-irreducibles if and only if if has length n, satisfies the Jordan-Dedekind chain condition, and has  n join-irreducibles and n meet-irreducibles (Theorem 3.1 on page 180 of Algebra Universalis, volume 11). I have it on good authority Farley regrets not referring to this paper, since I hear he did initially use the theorem when proving the results in the Farley-Schmidt paper (although Dr.Schmidt---and, in the paper, Farley and Schmidt---used a different approach).

Comment: Professor Stanley writes above, "I don't know whether the following is true: let $L$ be a finite lattice with maximal chain of length $n$. If $L$ has exactly $n$ join-irreducibles and $n$ meet-irreducibles, then $L$ is distributive." If we read this as "some maximal chain has length $n$", consider the non-modular 5-element lattice $N_5$.  We are in the territory of Professor Markowsky's "extremal lattices." If we read this as "every maximal chain has length $n$", the aforementioned Theorem 3.1 of Professor Markowsky says the lattice is distributive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is of course the classic criterion of excluded lattices.  A lattice is distributive if does not contain either $M_3$ or $N_5$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice) for definitions).  An easier criterion to check for large lattices is Birkhoff's two chain theorem: if a lattice is generated by two [chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Chains), then it is distributive.  (The converse is not true.)  You can find this in Birkhoff's book *Lattice Theory*.

Comment: Birkhoff's theorem states that a *modular* lattice generated by two chains is distributive. It is not true that any lattice generated by two chains is distributive.

Comment: You're completely right.  My subconscious bias in favor of lattices of modules: revealed.

Comment: (Professor George Markowsky has asked me to make the following comment.) Theorem 2 from Some Combinatorial Aspects of Lattice Theory, Proc. Univ. of Houston Lattice Theory Conf., 1973, 36-68 states: THEOREM 2. Let L be a finite lattice. The following are equivalent. (a) L has length n, satisfies the Jordan-Dedekind chain condition, has n join-irreducible elements and n meet-irreducible elements. (b) L has n join-irreducible elements, and every connected (maximal) chain between I and 0 has length n. (c) L is distributive and has n join-irreducible elements.

Comment: (continuing Professor Markowsky's comment) In a Hasse diagram of a finite lattice, the join-irreducible elements are the nodes that have only one edge going downward, while the meet-irreducible elements are the nodes that have only one edge going upward from them. For the examples given: (i) has 4 join-irreducibles (a, b, c, d), 3 meet-irreducibles (c, d, e) and all maximal chains have length 3 so it is not distributive.

(ii) has 3 join-irreducibles (a, b, d), 3 meet-irreducibles (a, c, d), and all maximal chains have length 3 so it is distributive.

Comment: (concluding Professor Markowsky's comment) It is the Cartesian product of the two-element chain and the three-element chain.

(iii) is not a lattice since a and b do not have a join.